# Recursively setting a value depending on range using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to word this but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
if (score >= 0 && score <= 10) overallScore = 0;
else if (score >= 11 && score <= 20) overallScore = 1;
else if (score >= 21 && score  <= 30) overallScore = 2;
else if (score >= 31 && score <= 40) overallScore = 3;
else if (score >= 91 && score <= 100) overallScore = 9;
...
```

Is there any way to recursively do this using a function?

Comment: Should we assume the value jumps from `31<->40` to `91<->100` or are there values in between (`41<->50`, `51<->60` etc.)?

Comment: Why do you want it recursively?

Comment: @Mathyn yes, and hard limit on anything over 100 sets overallScore to 9

Comment: @trincot just an exercise. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 overallScore = Math.max(0, Math.floor((score - 1) / 10));
```

no need for recursion. But if you need that:

```
  const getOverall = score => score <= 10 ? 0 : getOverall(score - 10) + 1;
```

Comment: Great answer thank you so much. Another thing is that I need to put a hard limit on score over 100. So anything over 100 would set overallScore to 9.

Comment: I guess I can just add one more line of if statement to check for it and set the overallScore to 9, but I was just wondering if we can do it in on line.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not really appropriate here, since you can get the required value in constant time. Recursion becomes interesting when you need at least *O(logn)* time.

But as you ask for it, here is one way to make it recursive:

```js
function range(score, depth = 0) {
    return score <= 10 || depth >= 9 ? 0 : range(score-10, depth+1) + 1;
}

console.log(range(0));   // 0
console.log(range(10));  // 0
console.log(range(11));  // 1
console.log(range(60));  // 5
console.log(range(91));  // 9
console.log(range(110)); // 9
```

Comment: why `depth` ? `score >= 100 ? 10` would be sufficient

Comment: Yes, but that really drills down to "why recursion"? :) Here I limit the return of a constant value to one constant value. If two, I might as well do it for the other 8.